# MobaXTerm (or other SFTP/SSH Clients) - "Elevated" SFTP Access

Tags: ssh, sftp

I'm using MobaXTerm on PC/Windows, playing with linux on raspberry pi.  When I SSH in, I can access the root folder in the image I'm using by:

```
sudo -i
/root/bin/remountfs_rw
```

But the SFTP screen to the left is still stuck without access to the root folder.  Is there a way to SFTP with root privledges in this program?  Or in ANY program?  I really like the GUI ability to download/edit/upload files for large tasks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just **playing**, you can do it the old way and enable root login over ssh. Then instead of doing `sudo` you connect as user `root` to your raspberry pi. The relevant lines should be in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`: `PermitRootLogin yes` needs to be set. Restart `sshd` afterwards (`systemctl restart sshd` -- normally runs fine even over SSH :) ). Additionally, you might need to configure a root password: `sudo -s` followed by `passwd`.

Note that both: root password and root login over SSH are disabled by default for security reasons. In case you need to operate such a system securely, think twice! Additionally, for any "secure" use case one should generally avoid password login in favour of keyfiles.

Finally, `root` GUI file management is actually very uncommon on Linux. It is not so much a security concern as a large danger of accidentally breaking something (it might be subtle like some trash file being created in a system directory which later causes package uninstallations to fail or it might be direct like accidentally unmounting an important filesystem etc.) Again, if it's just "playing", it might be OK. For real servers it is usually unacceptable.